# How have the 'gift' transponders on ISRO's GSAT-9 been used by other countries?

Tags: communication, geostationary, isro

**edit:** It's been <s>seven months</s>. <s>close to two years</s> <s>close to two years *and* seven months</s> over three years now, have any of the 'gift' transponders been used or at least tested yet by the gift recipient nation?

---

The BBC news item [India launches 'invaluable' South Asia satellite](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-39814455) describes the 'gifting' or zero-cost licensing of transponders on the recently launched [GSAT-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSAT-9#Payload) to other South Asian countries.

> So it seems Mr Modi is placing the ISRO in a new orbit by providing this space-based platform that would have cost the participating nations almost $1,500m (£1,158m).
>
> According to the government, the satellite will enable a full range of services to India's neighbours in telecommunication and broadcasting areas such as television, direct-to-home (DTH) services, education, telemedicine, weather forecasting and disaster management support.

Is it possible for one transponder to simultaneously support all or many of those services, or would a country have to pick just one of them? I don't know the total bandwidth available from each transponder. I'm wondering if the idea is more that the transponder would allow experimentation and pilot studies, rather than a full range of services?

Comment: Related: http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/pm-narendra-modis-space-diplomacy-turns-satellite-launch-into-mini-saarc-summit/articleshow/58542337.cms